# opencv2 covariance matrix strange results

Tags: opencv, covariance

The following code gives inconsistent covariance matrix sizes.

```
cv::Mat A = (cv::Mat_<float>(3,2) << -1, 1, -2, 3, 4, 0);
cv::Mat covar1, covar2, covar3, covar4, mean;
calcCovarMatrix(A, covar1, mean, CV_COVAR_NORMAL | CV_COVAR_ROWS);
calcCovarMatrix(A, covar2, mean, CV_COVAR_SCRAMBLED | CV_COVAR_ROWS);
calcCovarMatrix(A, covar3, mean, CV_COVAR_NORMAL | CV_COVAR_COLS);
calcCovarMatrix(A, covar4, mean, CV_COVAR_SCRAMBLED | CV_COVAR_COLS);

std::cout << "size: " << covar1.size() << "\n";
std::cout << "size: " << covar2.size() << "\n";
std::cout << "size: " << covar3.size() << "\n";
std::cout << "size: " << covar4.size() << "\n";
```

`covar1` and `covar2` should have the same size because they both describe the covariance over the rows, and `covar3` and `covar4` should have the same size because they both describe the covariance over the columns, respectively. However, the output is:

```
size: [2 x 2]
size: [3 x 3]
size: [3 x 3]
size: [2 x 2]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`calcCovarMatrix()` docs](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?#calccovarmatrix), specifically say that when using `CV_COVAR_SCRAMBLED` *"The covariance matrix will be `nsamples x nsamples`."*

Comment: Ok. As a follow-up question: why does covar3, the covariance matrix over the columns have size 3x3? There are only 2 columns in matrix A. To compare, in Matlab, the same covariance matrix has size 2x2.

Comment: The `CV_COVAR_NORMAL` docs say : "covar will be a *square* matrix of the same size as the total number of elements in each input vector." With `CV_COVAR_COLS`, you have two, 3-element vectors, thus the result is a square 3x3 matrix.

Comment: OK. Got it, the naming of the constants is very counterintuitive.